# jQuery remove all except first and last numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array

```
var aa = ["500", "600", "700", "800", "900", "1000", "1100", "1200"]
```

I need to remove all except the first one and the last one. The problem though is sometimes my array has only one value `var = ["500"]` and I need to keep it as it is the first value.

```
 aa.slice(1,-1);
```

Slicing `["500"]` will result in `[]` and I need `["500"]`.

Comment: Can't you have if statement for checking number of elements? (one extra line and someone looking at your code will know what's going on :))

Comment: The last element shouldn't have a comma. Is it an absolute necessity that a solution be jQuery or is JavaScript ok? If it is, please indicate that with the JavaScript tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just alternative:

```
var bb = aa.length > 2 ? [aa[0], aa[aa.length - 1]] : aa;
```

Comment: or `if(aa.length > 2) aa = [aa[0], aa[aa.length - 1]]` if you don't want to change the var name.

Comment: is there a way to remove las two zeros? Instead 500, I'll have 5?

Comment: @JoshuaNa `aa[0].replace(/0/g,'')`

Comment: @GeneR, this will replace all zeros. Look at my updated solution below

Answer (score 2):

simple and easy (this will keep the array and if there is 2 of them (first and last), if you don't need that, change to arr.length > 1)

```
var arr = ["100", "200", "300", "400", "100200"];

if (arr.length > 2) {
    arr = [arr.shift(), arr.pop()]
}

arr[0] = arr[0].replace(/00$/, "");
arr[1] = arr[1].replace(/00$/, "");

console.log(arr);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/87dgkeeh/3/

Comment: this gives me the opposict [2, 3], I need [1, 4]

Comment: great, is there a way to remove las 2 zeros so instead of having 1200, it will be 12 and so on

Comment: Here, I have updated the answer. If initial solution answers your question, can you please mark it as accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
var aa = ["500", "600", "700", "800", "900", "1000", "1100", "1200"]
[aa.shift(), aa.pop()].filter(function(n){ return n != undefined })
// => Array [ "500", "1200" ]

var aa = ["500"]
[aa.shift(), aa.pop()].filter(function(n){ return n != undefined })
// => Array [ "500" ]
```

Comment: Isn't an array of 1 giving you `[String, Undefined]`?

Comment: What in case there is only one element?